# How do I set up a vertically split terminal for the vim-slime plugin?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, slime, terminal-emulator

For the [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) plugin, these are my settings:

```
let g:slime_target = "vimterminal"
let g:slime_paste_file = "$HOME/.slime_paste"
let g:slime_vimterminal_cmd = "sbcl --noinform --load " . @%
let g:slime_vimterminal_config = {"term_opencmd": "vert term | buffer %d", "term_finish": "close"}
```

What I wish to do is to have my terminal vertically split upon opening. Currently, it splits my terminal horizontally. I did some research and found out that I can manipulate [these](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#%3Aterminal) settings for `slime_vimterminal_config`. My idea is to run `vert term` and pipe that to my screen buffer, as seen above. This is still not splitting my screen vertically. Does anyone familiar with the plugin know what to do?

Comment: Have you tried steps discussed [here](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime/issues/168), in particular: `let g:slime_vimterminal_config = { "vertical": 1 }`?